# How to Export Images from an Image List in VS2005?

Tags: .net, imagelist

Using Visual Studio 2005, is there a way to export the images in an Image List to individual files on my PC?  Using the IDE, I select the Image List and view its properties.  In the "Images" property, I launch the Images Collection Editor dialog.  I can only add and remove images, but I cannot find a way to export an image that is already in the list.

Why?  The developer who made the original list has left our company and I need the images for an ASP.NET application (will convert to .jpeg).

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What kind of a list is it? Is this in C# or VB.NET? Are the images stored in a drop down list?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can write some simple code to export the images.  You don't mention which language you are using, so here is the solution in both C# and VB.

**C#**

```
for (int x = 0; x < imageList1.Images.Count; ++x)
{
    Image temp = imageList1.Images[x];
    temp.Save("image" + x + ".bmp");
}
```

**VB**

```
For x As Integer = 0 To imageList1.Images.Count - 1
    Dim temp As Image = imageList1.Images(x)
    temp.Save("image" & x & ".bmp")
Next
```

Comment: I agree with your answer - I was hoping for a Visual Studio option that I was not aware of.  Thank you for the above code, I'm in C# and it looks good!  I guess this is the only soluntion.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that according to the docs, the image returned from the `Images` collection indexer is a separate copy that really ought to be disposed by the caller when they're done with it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz38zyat(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If anyone is here and gets "A generic error occurred in GDI+", check your file path in the Save().  If the path doesn't exist you'll get that error and go down a whole other path of nonsense.  Once I had the path correct, this little bit of code worked like a charm!

Comment: temp.Save(imageList1.Images.Keys[x]); // Save with original filename

Answer (score 3):

On [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/Extracting_Embedded_Image.aspx) there is example application how to do this.

I've created a **new version** from Embedded Image Grabber which supports:

- png images
- jpg images
- gif images
- Save all images at once to a folder

SourceCode can be found [here](https://github.com/StefH/EmbeddedImageGrabber).

Comment: works good. just remember to download the source code and recompile with latest framework