# C# Toolbar Image Collection Editor

Tags: c#, winforms, image, collections, toolbar

I have an application with a tool bar and an Image Collection. The problem is that I do not have the original images and I need to create another tool bar with some of the same buttons. Is there a way to save the Images Collection from the tool bar to a file?

I tried extracting the images from a resource file but I do not know which one has the images stored in.

Comment: Hi @UweKeim. Sorry I forgot to indicate. Yes it is windows forms, VS2010 in Windows7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I did not find an answer for my question, I managed to get the images by reading the tool bar image list and saving each one to a file according to the given image key.

```
for (int x = 0; x < this.imageListToolbar3small.Images.Count; ++x)
        {
            Image temp = this.imageListToolbar.Images[x];
            temp.Save(this.imageListToolbar.Images.Keys[x] + ".png");
        }
```

This came from an answer to this question: [How to Export Images from an Image List in VS2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729417/how-to-export-images-from-an-image-list-in-vs2005)

I just added the code after the InitializeComponent call and saved all images in debug mode. I did not needed to run the full application.

If anyone does have a better idea or a small application to retrieve images from a tool bar using only the resource file, that would be appreciated. I will not mark as an answer since it is more a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

```
foreach (ToolBarButton b in toolBar.Buttons)
{
  //can be negative, for separators, because separators don't have images
  if (b.ImageIndex >= 0)
  {
    Image i = toolBar.ImageList.Images[b.ImageIndex];
    i.Save(b.ImageIndex + ".png");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to recover images from a private ImageList member of a Control. I used the following code (Sorry, it's VB but s/b easy to refactor)

```
    Dim cntrl = New TheClassWithThePrivateImageList
    Dim pi As Reflection.PropertyInfo, iml As System.Windows.Forms.ImageList, propName = "ThePropertyName"
    pi = cntrl.GetType.GetProperty(propName, Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    iml = CType(pi.GetValue(cntrl), System.Windows.Forms.ImageList)
    For Each key In iml.Images.Keys
        Dim image As Drawing.Image = iml.Images.Item(key)
        image.Save($"{propName}_{key}")
    Next
```